# What control can be used to display txt files as well as pfd and .doc

Tags: wpf, windows, forms, controls

I'm relatively new to windows forms programming and was looking for a control that could be used to display both .txt, pdf, and doc files. When I first started googling for a solution I was led to the possibility of using the wpf xps control, but I would have to figure out how to integrate that within a win form app and still wasn't clear as to whether it would solve all my problems. Any guidance on this will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In general, I wouldn't do that (try to find a single control that can do everything).  Instead I'd think about creating different controls for different types of content and toggling the visible state on the control depending on what content you're displaying.

Comment: I thought about that as well, but was hoping maybe someone here has used the xps page viewer control or has solved a similar issue and could provide some general guidance...